# set DATE column default value with another column(VARCHAR2(8)),error ora-00904

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

```
create table T_XXX
(
   DATE_POST VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
   DATE_GET DATE DEFAULT TO_DATE(SUBSTR("DATE_POST",1,8),'YYYYMMDD')
);
```

Error:

> ORA-00904:"DATE_POST"

Why does this happen?

My Oracle version is 12c

Comment: May I ask why you'd even _want_ to do this?  Why would you want to keep a date in both a DATE and a VARCHAR2 column?  Just keep it in the DATE column. If you want to see it in a given string format, just apply a to_char() to it at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that won't work.

But, as you're on 12c, create a *virtual column*. For example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> create table test
  2    (date_post varchar2(8),
  3     date_get  date generated always as (to_date(date_post, 'yyyymmdd'))
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (date_post) values ('20200501');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

DATE_POS DATE_GET
-------- ----------
20200501 01.05.2020

SQL>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Because you can't reference another column in DEFAULT clause.